# How can I get flawless square gems to drop in Reaper of Souls?

Tags: diablo-iii

Prior to Reaper of Souls, *flawless square gems* were the highest level gem that could be dropped.  With the expansion, *Marquis gems* are the normal gem pop for a level 70 character.

How can I farm flawless square gems to complete some achievements?

Comment: Create alts until you have all of them. There is no other way.

Comment: Yes it is ... doh.  Deleted and undeleted to leave it as a signpost.

Comment: @Assylum Your information is incorrect, see the linked question.